# Using emailjs to send inline attachment via javascript

Tags: javascript, email-attachments

This does not seem to work for me: 
1. Create a template and use the inline attachment
2. Use {{{file}}} for the attachment content in the Template.

Send the base64 attachment contents in the javascript parameters.

I can see the base64 contents in the emailjs Log, but the attachment does not get sent.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, and finally I had to send image in the attachments params like this:

```
[{
        data: body,
        alternative: true
    },
    {path: "path/image/image.png", type:"image/png", headers:{"Content-ID":"<name_image.png>"}}
],
```

In body variable, which is an html body, I referenced the image like this:

```
<img height="40" weidth="40" src="name_image.png" alt="name">
```

and it worked perfectly to me
I hope it helps